# Wordpress How can I transfer users to a database that already contains users?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need some help please with wordpress database table called wp_users.

I migrated the old site to a new server together with the users.

Customers also registered on live site after turning the old one down,so i cant just delete the table.

Also in the new server after i turn it live.

My question is , how can I transfer the **wp_users** table from old database into the new database that also has **wp_users** without **losing any user** ?

Maybe there is a way update or merge the tables?
Thank You.

Comment: I don't know much about wordpress, so I don't know if there are any other related tables that would be affected, but if it's just that one you can do a mysql dump from the old db and load the file into the new one.

Comment: @Don'tPanic so basicay this dump will only add the rows that i dont have ?

Comment: The dump will create a file with all the rows from the old db. When you load that file in the new db, depending on the load settings, it will either replace or ignore entries in the new table with duplicate indexes.

Comment: The load function is https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: @Don'tPanic ok i did it , it imported everything from the old db  and removed the registered users from today from the new db .i wonder why , any ideea?

Comment: How did you do the dump and import?

Comment: @Don'tPanic this is old db with table wp_users  see img https://ibb.co/n1JJTk , i chose that input there like you said and pressed go,saved it on desktop.
and then in new db i pressed import.The old db is just overwriting everything and deletes the new one that is there.

Comment: It exports the data as an SQL script. If you had "Add DROP TABLE" checked, then in the beginning of the SQL script it will drop and recreate the table before inserting the new rows.

Comment: @Don'tPanic then how should i do it ? because if i just export the wp_users table and try to import it in the new databse where i also have wp_users i get error that table also exist.Also i can lose users right?For example in the new database i have 10500 users and in old database i have 1600

Comment: Make sure ids don't mess up between tables (old and new) `wp_users`, `wp_usermeta` and whatever other custom tables have records with user ids

Comment: @IgorYavych it should not mess right ? i mean its the same wordpress and everything from the old server .The problem is the old server was live untill yesterday and people registered.And the new server was on since this morning and i also got some people registered